# How to insert selected valuemember from combo box to gridview, and gridview to database

Tags: c#, sql-server, gridview

```
for (int i = 0; i < DGV_NewPurchaseReq.Rows.Count ; i++)
{
    if (con.State != ConnectionState.Open)
        con.Open();

    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_prList_Insert", con))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@itemID", Convert.ToInt32(DGV_NewPurchaseReq.Rows[i].Cells["ItemCode"].Value));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prQty", Convert.ToInt32(DGV_NewPurchaseReq.Rows[i].Cells["Qty"].Value));
        // want to insert valuememeber of Requestor Name as empID from combo box ??
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empID", (DGV_NewPurchaseReq.Rows[i].Cells["RequestBy"].Value));
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem you are facing?

Comment: How is the combo box column set up? We have to assume it actually has a `DisplayMember` and/or `ValueMember`. I am guessing that you may want the combo boxes `FormattedValue` as opposed to just `Value` which should be the combo box cells `ValueMember` anyway. So, it is not clear, which one you want. `Value` “should” return the `ValueMember`, and this appears to be what you want to begin with… ?

Comment: It is better to setup your DataGridView with a DataSource so when there is a need to iterate rows you iterate the underlying data rather than the actual DataGridView. So when setting up the DataGridViewComboBox with `DisplayMember`, `ValueMember` and `DataPropertyName`. So now in a `for` to get a value use `table.Rows[rowIndex].Field<int>("RequestBy");`.